How to sync elastic search with a multi tenant microservice domain splitted database?
we have an application developed within the last 3 years. The app has a multi tenant systen in which we have 2 kinds of data bases: global (e.g. users, 1 user can be working in several tenants) and tenant sensitve (so tenant1, tenant2 etc) with sensible data that aren`t allowed to touch each other (e.g. patient data).
The app has around 30 services in a micro/mini-service idea where a bunch of domains are splitted. The split is happening for a tenant on schema within a database. E.g. Patient and Lab data are 2 schema of each tenant database.
Now we want to have several searches, each search serves a speical usecase. E.g. the frontend shows all patient data -> patientsearch, frontend shows all lab data -> lab search.
This is a diagram of what I just described: https://imgur.com/a/UKcyBVj
My problem is here, that thought this mutlitenant-domainsplitted databases / schemas it is very expensive to get the data together which I need for a elasticsearch index.
E.g.: If a patient information gets updated by the patientservice I need to: 1) go to the labservice and read the lab information to have all data I need for updating the labsearch index in ES, then updating it 2) the same patient now needs all subinformations (e.g. email adresses) from the same database to update the patientsearch index in ES then
This example is just a simple case of way more complexe usecases we hav in the system in whih we need to do calls over calls to other services to get the domaininformations together, which all hit basicly the same database from the same tenant but from other services and with that we have a huge amount of overhead in our system.
Additional to that we need to solve the "what happens if something breaks" problem - everything at the moment is triggert in EF Core within the dbcontext -> From there with a check on the changetracker we send an event to a so called elasticsearch service to start the algorythm to enrich all the data between the domain services. So if something breakes here, the search will never been updated. For that we need to find a way to a) find out there is a missing information between ES and DB and b) sync that again.
So this is a very complex szenario, hope someone will be able to bring some ideas to the table :)

Did you do any design work before implementing the system.  You have a frontend and a backend and error checking should be done in front end.  Schemas are used for error checking and it looks like you want to avoid creating the schemas. What do you mean by expensive?  Long execution time?  May be you should invest in a better database that runs quicker.  Database should be install on the fastest machine you can but, with the most number of cores, and filled with all the memory that it can hold so time to execute is quick.
